# Asserting two JSON results that are output in random order

Tags: java, json, unit-testing, switch-statement, assert

When unit testing, I need to assert two `JSON` results that populate a map in random order.

Both `JSONs` have the same schema but most contents do vary.

These come from a `Kafka` Stream (`JavaPairDStream` when testing) and are extracted from a `tuple2` then converted from `JSON Strings` to Map using `Jackson ObjectMapper`. I am using `queueStream` but oddly the order is random when testing with `Spark` workflow.

EDIT: I have decided to use a `List` since a set might change the order...

Here is the `Java` code:

```
//Create a list to store maps
List<Map<String, Object>> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(map1);
list.add(map2);

//Traverse each map in list and apply correct assertions
for (Map<String, Object> map : list) {
    //if Event is "Event1", assertions for "Event1" Event
    if (map.get("Event").toString().equals("Event1")) {
        Assert.assertEquals(map.get("Event").toString(), "Event1");
        more assertions go here...
    } else {
        //if Event is not "Event1", assertions for "Event2" Event
        Assert.assertEquals(map.get("Event").toString(), "Event2");
        more assertions go here...
    }
}
```

Note: This works fine right now since I am only working with two distinct Events. But I would like to learn how to handle this situation with scalability.

Comment: What language? and can you show us example code (JSON and your try)?

Comment: Updated. Thanks for helping, @HubertGrzeskowiak!

Comment: Please consider stating the problem first, next time. You are presenting a half-baked solution and nobody really knows what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the hamcrest matcher [`containsInAnyOrder`](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#containsInAnyOrder(java.util.Collection)). You may have to write a custom matcher to make the code readable.

```
List<Map<String,Object>> myJsonObjectsInRandomOrder;
...
assertThat(myJsonObjectsInRandomOrder, containsInAnyOrder(new CustomMatcher("Event1", ... ), new CustomMatcher("Event2", ... )));
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, tonicsoft. Your answer looks like it's comparing the two JSON outputs. But I am not comparing the two JSONs. I am making assertions to both JSON outputs to their respective expected outputs.

Comment: Why are you doing the assertions on two objects and not one by one then?

Comment: ah I completely misunderstood the question. Answer updated!

Comment: Aren't I doing the assertions one by one by using a foreach loop? The order in which the JSON outputs are streamed in and populated to the Set is unknown. And therefore I have the if/else inside of the foreach loop. I think that is pretty clear. @HubertGrzeskowiak

Comment: Thank you, tonicsoft! I will try that and see.